# Trying to dual boot but Ubuntu installer does not see Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-legacy

I am running Windows 10 on a Cyberpower PC with a gigabyte MB Model # GA-78LMT-USB3. I want to keep it for now and have Ubuntu running along side it. But when I try to install it does not see Windows.

I have tried to partition my hard drive but I am nervous to install it into the new partition. My BIOS is in legacy mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installer of 14.04.1 LTS doesn't recognize Windows 7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544705/installer-of-14-04-1-lts-doesnt-recognize-windows-7). Also, your question is unclear. "It does not see Windows" could mean any of a dozen things. If the references question and answers don't help, you *must* clarify if you expect help that's better than a random shot in the dark.

Comment: @RodSmith then vote as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Choose something else/manual partition. Make a X GB free space partition and set root point to `/`
then install ubuntu. After finishing the installation, follow boot repair to get windows 10 listed.
Repairing boot:
1. open a terminal and paste and hist enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

2. then paste below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

3. finally this command:

```
sudo boot-repair
```

4. finally reboot and windows will be there in boot menu..